# Show only wireless system settings on Android 3

Tags: android

This code works perfectly:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

But Android 3 show also another preferences. How do I can show to user only wireless settings?

UPD This code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.Settings");
startActivity(intent);
```

starts a mobile settings. Is there something like that for wi-fi (turn in\off, setting ip-address etc)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can show only the wireless settings fragment by adding the following extras to your intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
i.putExtra(":android:show_fragment", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
i.putExtra(":android:no_headers", true);

startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Great answer...If I want to show WiFi & Ethernet...How ca I?

Answer (score 1):

> But Android 3 show also another preferences.

The activity you are starting is part of the Settings application, which you did not write. The Settings application can display whatever it wants. In the case of tablets, the Settings application will generally show all preferences, with the one tied to your `Intent` action be the currently-selected one.

> How do I can show to user only wireless settings?

Write your own firmware with your own implementation of the Settings app that does what you want, and install that firmware on the user's device.

Answer (score 0):

You can access only Wifi settings by using this

```
Intent i = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);
startActivity(i);
```

Extra options(for back and next buttons)

```
Intent i = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);
i.putExtra("extra_prefs_show_button_bar", true);
startActivity(i);
```