# How to launch an Android SubSettings Fragment?

Tags: android

For example, how do I launch User Settings?  It's not implemented as its own Activity, so I'm not sure how to start it.

Below are some other similar questions but these are either more general or more specific. My question is about starting an arbitrary SubSettings fragment.

[How do I call a specific PreferenceFragment from a PreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672487/how-do-i-call-a-specific-preferencefragment-from-a-preferenceactivity)

[Show only wireless system settings on Android 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773188/show-only-wireless-system-settings-on-android-3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can launch most Android Settings sub-screens by starting the SubSettings Activity and including the **:android:show_fragment** extra with the appropriate fully-qualified class name of an existing Android PreferenceFragment subclass.

For example, to start UserSettings:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings -e :android:show_fragment com.android.settings.users.UserSettings
```

To start DeviceInfoSettings:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings -e :android:show_fragment com.android.settings.DeviceInfoSettings
```

These examples use 'adb shell am start', but in principle you could invoke these in Java code (EDIT: Unfortunately you need to be signed with the system key, otherwise you get a SecurityException). Notice that the key for this extra has a colon at the front of it. To find other Settings, checkout the Android source and look for subclasses of PreferenceFragment in the packages/apps/Settings.

The situation was different in Froyo and before. In those days Activities were used to implement Settings sub-screens, so one could launch directly into a sub-screen (for example SoundAndDisplaySettings) by the usual method of calling startActivity() with a ComponentName or action String. This mechanism still works for some Settings sub-screens. For example, to bring up a wifi picker, you can use

```
adb shell am start -a android.net.wifi.PICK_WIFI_NETWORK
```

Comment: Do you know perhaps how to reach the new "Process Stats" screen, which is reachable via the "developers options", starting from Kitkat ?

Comment: adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings -e :android:show_fragment com.android.settings.applications.ProcessStatsUi

Comment: It doesn't work. It shows "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent". Also, how did you get it?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately you get a SecurityException if you try this programmatically without being signed with the system key, but it works for me when using the command-line. Regarding how I figured this out, I just examined the AOSP source code.

Comment: But I used ADB too, via the command line. About how to find it, in which file/s did you look at?

Comment: how can i put this in startActivity(...).  I have a system level app that on button click i want to pen up the subsettings screen with a fragment like system update screen.

Comment: To start a SubSettings fragment from Java code, use: 
startActivity(new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.SubSettings")).putExtra(":android:show_fragment", "com.android.settings.DeviceInfoSettings"));
(replace DeviceInfoSettings with whatever you are interested in).

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to do this for Lollipop?

Comment: For me the "Settings" app crashes right after launch. I'm on Lollipop, and trying this method from a terminal emulator on the device (not adb from a PC), and with root access ("su" command).

Comment: @JosephJohnson Suppose i have app that needs "PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" permission, how do I get to the correct screen using this method?

Answer (score 3):

for MM :

```
am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings -e :settings:show_fragment com.android.settings.applications.RunningServices
```